# Easiest way to create a demo in gh-pages (in keep insync with master)

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a repo where I have the following structure

```
index.html
src/
dist/
```

I have only `index` and `src/` inside git (dist/ is ignored) but I want to create a gh-pages that only has `index` and `/dist`.

What is the best way to keep them both in sync? Atm I have to do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous integration.

Use some GitHub integration like [Circle CI](https://github.com/integrations/circle-ci) or [Travis CI](https://github.com/integrations/travis-ci) that gets notified of every push in your `master` branch and builds and deploys to your `gh-pages` branch.

You can read [any](https://gist.github.com/domenic/ec8b0fc8ab45f39403dd) [of](https://medium.com/@nthgergo/publishing-gh-pages-with-travis-ci-53a8270e87db#.8svkmd1wq) [this](http://www.stackbuilders.com/news/dr-hakyll-crea-una-pagina-de-github-con-hakyll-y-circleci) [posts](http://frankiesardo.github.io/posts/2015-04-19-automate-everything-with-circleci.html) to get some ideas of how to configure all this.

If you want all of this to happen in a local repository, and only push the `gh-pages` branch to GitHub, you can try to run some `post-commit` hook that builds the site on to `dist/` and `push`es it to GitHub.

It's a bit more awkward, since you probably don't want to push *every* commit you do, but it's doable. Also, this should be a bit slow, so you probably want to do the build as a background job.

Comment: Its only a simple local project and github.

Comment: Sorry, @SuperUberDuper - I don't get what you're trying to say with this comment.

Comment: I don't really want to set up a CI solution for this. I want to handle it from some simple local command line stuff. I thought there would be some methods out there.

Comment: I've added some comments about using git hooks for hacking something up.